# Components blocking each other

Tags: spring-boot

I'm a newbie in developing with SpringBoot, so maybe this question will sound silly, but I hope someone will be able to show me the error of my ways.

I have a SpringBoot application with 4 Components. One of them processes input files and writes records into database, while the other three read the records, process them according to component configuration and send the result to a Web Service.

My problem is that sometimes there's a lot of files to be processed, so the "reader" Component takes a bit longer to finish. What I've noticed is that, while it's running, none of the other Components are starting. Since the data is relatively time sensitive, it is important for me that the processing Components run periodically and asynchronously.

I have used @EnableAsync in the main Application and I've marked all Components as @Async, yet the blocking problem still occurs. I was under the impression that the scheduled Components will be executed independent of each other. There are no shared resources between Components and even if they were, I would understand that a Component starts and blocks, but the Components (threads) are not started at all (I have a trace entry as a first line of each Component).

What should I look at? Is this how it is supposed to work? If yes, I will then start async threads from the Components or find another way, but I thought I can get by without all of that by using SpringBoot.

Any and all answers will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend either using Spring Batch or Spring Integration to solve this. Both are explicitly designed to help with this sort of thing.

Comment: I've taken a glance at them but I don't see how they can help without significant changes to the code/application. Can you be so kind to give me more details?

Comment: Spring Batch is designed for processing large amounts of data, in defined steps, allowing for things like rolling back and restarting if a step fails. It's optimized for performance, by for example, reading in chunks of data at a time rather than record at a time.

Spring Integration can be thought of an embedded ESB, like Mule, but bolted into your application. It allows processing to take place in a well defined sequence, using connected pipes at its heart, allowing you to trigger certain behaviour based on events. There's a certain cross over with Spring Batch & SI can also call SB flows.